# Validate Frontend Form in Magento

Tags: javascript, form-validation

I have the below *Calculator Form* which I'm creating in Magento that I would like to be able to use Magento's in-built JavaScript validations, even though I need to validate on a button click rather than a form submit.

Most of the logic is done through jQuery from a *phtml* file that I've added with a custom module, that has it's own frontend route, basically example.com/calculator.

Below is a simplified version of what I have:

```
<div id="calculator">
    <form id="calculator_form">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2><span class="count">1</span> Enter Values</h2>
                <div class="row-section">
                    <div class="row-content">
                        <label>Length</label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" class="height-val input-text required-entry">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-content">
                        <label>Width</label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" class="wall-width input-text required-entry">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
    <button onclick="calculate();" class="button"><span><span>Calculate</span></span></button>
    <div class="result">
        <strong>Your Results</strong>
        <p class="result-text"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
        var calculator_form= new VarienForm('calculator_form', true);
        // Callculations & Much More Form Logic is Here
        // Includes a Lot of jQuery
        jQuery('.result-text').html('Your results are:' + results);
    }
</script>
```

I kind of have it working with `var calculator_form= new VarienForm('calculator_form', true);` but it's not showing the validation message, it just highlights the first form field when I click on the **Calculate** button.

What am I missing? Any help would be really appreciated.
`js/prototype/validation.js` is being loaded on the page.

### UPDATE

I almost got it working with the below.  I put `var calculatorForm= new VarienForm('calculator-form', true);` into a separate script tag, and moved the button within the `<form>` tags.  The validation works properly but when I click on the button it refreshes the page when there are no validation errors.

```
<div id="calculator">
    <form id="calculator-form">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2><span class="count">1</span> Enter Values</h2>
                <div class="row-section">
                    <div class="row-content">
                        <label>Length</label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" class="height-val input-text required-entry">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-content">
                        <label>Width</label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" class="wall-width input-text required-entry">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="submit" onclick="calculate();" class="button"><span><span>Calculate</span></span></button>
    </form>
    <div class="result">
        <strong>Your Results</strong>
        <p class="result-text"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
        // Callculations & Much More Form Logic is Here
        // Includes a Lot of jQuery
        jQuery('.result-text').html('Your results are:' + results);
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var calculatorForm= new VarienForm('calculator-form', true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I had to use `Validation.validate($('calc-height'));` in the same function being called by the button, to validate individual fields.

Works pretty well, but if anyone knows of another way, I'd be interested to hear.

```
<div id="calculator">
    <form id="calculator-form">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2><span class="count">1</span> Enter Values</h2>
                <div class="row-section">
                    <div class="row-content">
                        <label>Length</label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="calc-height" name="calc-height" class="required-entry">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-content">
                        <label>Width</label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="calc-width" name="calc-width" class="required-entry">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="submit" onclick="calculate();" class="button"><span><span>Calculate</span></span></button>
    </form>
    <div class="result">
        <strong>Your Results</strong>
        <p class="result-text"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
        v1 = Validation.validate($('calc-height'));
        v2 = Validation.validate($('calc-width'));
        if(v1 && v2) {
            // Callculations & Much More Form Logic is Here
            // Includes a Lot of jQuery
            jQuery('.result-text').html('Your results are:' + results);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in form id
var myForm= new VarienForm('#calculator form', true);

Correct base on your code is
var myForm= new VarienForm('#calculator_form', true);

Also make sure validation.js is loaded

**Edit:**
 that's a start. 
Do you have any console errors? 
Some how validation can't append the error div... 
Also try to put the new VarienForm in separate script tags

**Edit 2:**
Try this separately

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    //< ![CDATA[ 
    var calculator_form = new VarienForm('calculator_form'); 
    //]]>
</script>
```